# Operation returned an invalid status 'unauthorized' when deploying Python app

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am following this guide to deploy python app on Azure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python-webapp?view=azure-devops

I was successfully able to clone the repo and authenticated through Github in Azure Portal Shell.

But I got above error when I tried to deploy the app using the following command.
`az webapp up -n PythonFlaskAppExampleApp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I had to manually create app-service from Azure Portal UI, as `az webapp up -n <your-appservice>` command didn't work. It deployed app successfully after creating it.

Answer (score 1):

We need to make sure that all the [configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python) has been done which building python webapp.
below are few key points where we need to look into:

1. For FlaskApp App service looks for App.py which has below content:

> ```
>  If application.py
> gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 application:app
>  If app.py
> gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 app:app
> ```

2. Check for customized build automations in [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#customize-build-automation)

Also below are few predefined configs which needs to be set, check them one by one based on your requirement:

```
    az group create -n <some_name> --location westus
    az appservice plan create --name <some_name> -g <some_name> --sku s1 --location westus --is-linux
    az webapp create -g <some_name> -n <some_globaly_unique_name> --plan <some_name> --runtime "PYTHON|3.7"
    az webapp config appsettings set -g <some_name> -n <some_globaly_unique_name> --settings WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE="1"
    az webapp config appsettings set -g <some_name> -n <some_globaly_unique_name> --settings SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true
    az webapp restart -n <some_globaly_unique_name> -g <some_name>

    git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/python-docs-hello-world
    cd .\python-docs-hello-world\
    Compress-Archive -Path * -DestinationPath package.zip
    az webapp deployment source config-zip -n <some_globaly_unique_name> -g <some_name> --src .\package.zip
```

Note: Check for your current versions and replace them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `az account set -s <Subscription ID>` first.

Even if you already logged in with the Azure CLI, that still may not pick a subscription for billing. You have to set that first. This is what solved the problem for me. The selected answer did it through the web portal, which does pick a subscription for you.

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation describing how the command solves the problem.